# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiimage, core-graphics, exc-bad-access

I develop a CGImage and it works fine when the program displays it on the screen using this:

```
[output_view.layer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject: (id) image waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Now, doing this crashes the application:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithCGImage: image)],nil,nil,nil);
```

I don't understand it at all. Here's the stack during the crash:

```
#0  0x33b5db6e in memmove (Line 65)
#1  0x341ddee2 in CGAccessSessionGetBytes
#2  0x31ab4488 in alphaProviderGetBytes
#3  0x341ddf52 in CGAccessSessionGetBytes
#4  0x31abbc80 in writeOne
#5  0x31abbdae in _CGImagePluginWriteJPEG
#6  0x31ab2ddc in CGImageDestinationFinalize
#7  0x3037eda2 in imageDataFromImageWithFormatAndProperties
#8  0x3037effc in imageDataFromImageRef
#9  0x3038ea3c in __-[PLAssetsSaver _saveImage:imageData:properties:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_1
#10 0x33c32680 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release
#11 0x33c32ba0 in _dispatch_worker_thread2
#12 0x33bd7250 in _pthread_wqthread
```

Here is the method with the problem:

```
-(void)captureOutput: (AVCaptureOutput *) captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer: (CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer fromConnection: (AVCaptureConnection *) conenction{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 
    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    UInt8 * image_data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    //Removed part here which modifies the CVPixelBuffer pixels with a particular algorithm.
    [bottom_view setNeedsDisplay];
    [bottom_view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:av/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1] waitUntilDone: YES];
    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data
    CGDataProviderDirectCallbacks providerCallbacks = { 0, GetBytePointer, ReleaseBytePointer, GetBytesAtPosition, 0 };
    CGDataProviderRef d_provider = CGDataProviderCreateDirect(image_data,pixels*4,&providerCallbacks);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate (width,height,8,32,bytesPerRow,colorSpace,kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst,d_provider,NULL,true,kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    //Draw image
    if (needs_photo) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithCGImage: image],nil,nil,nil);
        needs_photo = NO;
    }
    if (recording) {
        [writer_input appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    }
    [output_view.layer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject: (id) image waitUntilDone:YES];
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    // Free up the context and color space
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(image);
    CGDataProviderRelease(d_provider);
    [pool drain];
 }
```

Thank you for any help with this problem.

Comment: Did you try retaining [UIImage imageWithCGImage: image] in your `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` call? This is merely a guess, because your code looks okay to me otherwise.

Comment: I've been looking at the stack. I don't understand it really because I don't understand arm assembly language but there is something weird. At one point on the stack the code stops at a mov operation. Now wouldn't that usually be at the top of the stack where a problem happens? It's not. Maybe I don't know how the stack information is displayed.

Comment: Ah, the arrow always points after the actual line you need to look at for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code instead of yours and see if it's working, maybe your input stream is faulty and not the save operation.

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

float width = 64;
float height = 64;

GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(width * height * 4);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, (width * height * 4), NULL);

// set up for CGImage creation
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, 0);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef],nil,nil,nil);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

[pool drain];
```

so

if this is working, add parts of your original code little by little to see when it crashes.

Comment: That code makes no sense. What's with the opengl for a start? Also I know what breaks it. It's when I add the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Comment: yes and this sample code creates an random image and saves it to the photo album. So I want you to test the saving without your camera stream. The opengl import is for using GLubyte

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), context);

It will solve your problem. If you still get the same problem please let me know. I would like to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but filling out the other arguments doesn't do anything.

Comment: I know this is like almost 3 years old.  But thanks for this answer.  Matthew was told the answer like 3 times in here and didn't listen.. but the exact same thing is happening to me and it's because I'm immediately releasing the uiimage after calling that.  So it's releasing the image before it's done saving it.  It fixed my prob,

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to keep the saving UIImage until it is successful to save in the photo library. The UIImageWriteToSavedPhotoAlbum has a delegate method to notify the completation of saving image.

Answer (score 0):

Your image data (or more likely, the UIImage object it's derived from) has been released or autoreleased once too often, or failed to be retained one or more times. No other explanation.

Comment: THanks for the answer but I've tried retaining the UIImage before going into that function and I've also removed CGImageRelease afterwards in case that did something. None of that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you obtain the original `CGImageRef`? Since it's crashing in `memmove()`, it sounds like you are specifying a block of image data which isn't fully allocated, or is prematurely freed. This means that it might successfully save about half of your image, but then crash on the other half, which might be out-of-bounds.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll edit the question is include the entire relevant method. I will remove some parts.

Comment: In the code you've provided, you seem to be assuming that the buffer contains an alpha channel, when (as far as I know) that may not actually be the case. Expecting the data to be longer than it actually is could certainly cause the issues you've been experiencing. Instead of hardcoding 32 bits and 4 bytes per pixel, you could divide `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow()` by `CVPixelBufferGetHeight()` and round down the result, and that should be the number of bytes per pixel.

Comment: Thank you but there definitely is an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused because you call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum from another thread than the main thread (I think you do because of the "output_view.layer performSelectorOnMainThread" some lines down.

Be aware that those UI-graphics functions are not fully threadsafe.

Perhaps try moving the "save to album" call into main thread's "setContent" function for testing. If it crashes there too i really don't know why it happens.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. I've tried using performSelectorOnMainThread... on it with failure. What do you mean by 'main thread's "setContent" function for testing'? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far assume that the crash is in `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`, but the line in the stack trace `imageDataFromImageRef` suggests to me that it's crashing in `[UIImage imageWithCGImage: image]`.  Perhaps you could move that call to a intermediate variable to find out for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are completely wrong here. It only crashes with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum().

Answer (score 0):

How you are calling the following method

```
-(void)captureOutput: (AVCaptureOutput *) captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer: (CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer fromConnection: (AVCaptureConnection *) conenction{
```

If you called this method using some other thread(other than Main Thread), then only you need to use `NSAutoReleasePool` Other wise it will release some variables, because of that it may crash.

And one more thing,

You are using this,

```
[output_view.layer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject: (id) image waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Why you are using `performSelector`, you can directly call the method like

```
[output_view.layer setContents:image];
```

Try the above those.
you may get solve the problem.

Regards,

Satya

Comment: Thankyou. Are you suggesting to remove the auto-release pool?

Comment: have you tried by putting normal method for "setContents" in place of perform selector.

Comment: Yes, that causes the application to fail. The image isn't placed on the layer.

Answer (score 0):

for me EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you using an object which no longer exist (I know it's not correct but thats the most reason if I get it). Debug all your objects / variables and see if they have still values in it.

try `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([[UIImage imageWithCGImage: image]retain],nil,nil,nil);`

Enable `NSZombieEnabled` and run again (Executable -> Arguments -> NSZombieEnabled = YES)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot about trying NSZombieEnabled. I will give it a shot. For me EXC_BAD_ACCESS means, an error has occurred, good luck.

Comment: NSZombieEnabled doesn't change anything. The crash is in a different thread so I can't view all the variables on that method. Or can I?

Comment: you can insert a NSLog() before each variable use :)

Comment: This is a different thread. It's no use debugging variables on this method when they must be fine as the method completes.

Comment: see if "CGImageRef image" is set and have you tried to retain the UIImage as described?

Comment: I did try to retain it before. It did nothing. And what do you mean by the first part of your comment?

Comment: can you debug the image-variable just to see if something is in there? or use an analyzer tool: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/

Comment: Usually when you debug, you hold the mouse over or click on the variable. I'm not sure which but I've done it before. I can't do anything like this in this case because the variables are long gone. The method has executed. It's the end of that. The crash is in another thread. THe thread created by UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having issues with this, I found in my particular case it was caused by one of these functions, not exactly sure but once I commented them all out all over my app it started to work

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
```